# Set Update Manager to install to sites/all/modules/contrib?

Tags: updating

I am able to use Update Manager to install new modules, instead of having to manually upload them. I previously put everything in `sites/all/modules`, but now have reorganized my modules into `sites/all/modules/contrib` and `sites/all/modules/custom` (for the modules I write or modify).

However, Update Manager is still installing new modules in `sites/all/modules`. Is it possible to tell Update Manager to install new modules in `sites/all/modules/contrib` instead? I looked for a setting somewhere, but can't find one (D7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To circumvent these (and other) issues, I typically use the [Drush command line utility](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to install and update new modules instead of the Update Manager.

For instance:

```
drush dl views --destination='sites/all/modules/contrib' # Download views to this path
drush dl uuid --destination='sites/all/modules/contrib' --select # Select other releases
drush en views views_ui  # Enable Views and Views UI
drush up ctools          # Update CTools
```

Drush also provides a number of other useful commands, and integrates very nicely with other modules. I highly recommend looking into using it if you haven't already!

Comment: Thanks. I figured I could do it with Drush, but hoped to make Update Manager work right. Turns out there's a sandbox project, [Better Update](http://drupal.org/sandbox/Milena/1215590), that allows install paths, and also an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1399026) has been filed for this capability.