# How to change module default path

Tags: 7, updating

I recently organized my modules in /sites/all/modules in 4 differents subfolders: contrib, custom, patches, migration.
It works very well, but after using the update manager, the new updated modules appears in /sites/all/modules instead of /sites/all/modules/contrib, so I have to move it manually to contrib.
How can I set the default module location to /sites/all/modules/contrib ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't find this issue before, it has been already reported here [Set Update Manager to install to sites/all/modules/contrib?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24367/set-update-manager-to-install-to-sites-all-modules-contrib?rq=1)

I knew about drush, but I was wondering if it could be done with the update-manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some steps:

1. Firstly, backup your database
2. Check-in your code into version control
3. Run following queries:

   UPDATE system SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib');

   UPDATE registry SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib');

   UPDATE registry_file SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib')

   1. Move folders
   2. Run: drush cc all